# Update blog option during create new blog?

Tags: multisite, hooks, options

I have situation where I want to update blog blog options during creation of new blog. I want to update options like, home, default_comment_status, default_ping_status permalinks structure, etc ...

So I created function:

```
function setup_multisite_action($data){
  $blog_id = (int) $data->blog_id;
  update_blog_option($blog_id, 'home', 'https://test.local');
  update_blog_option($blog_id, 'default_comment_status', 'closed');
  update_blog_option($blog_id, 'default_ping_status', 'closed');
}
add_action( 'wp_insert_site', 'setup_multisite_action', 50, 1 );
```

But it won't work. I tried to use hook `wpmu_new_blog` and actually in this case this works!

```
function setup_multisite_action($blog_id){

  update_blog_option($blog_id, 'home', 'https://test.local');
  update_blog_option($blog_id, 'default_comment_status', 'closed');
  update_blog_option($blog_id, 'default_ping_status', 'closed');
}
add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', 'setup_multisite_action', 50, 1 );
```

BUT! this hook is **deprecated** and it telling me to use **`wp_insert_site`**.

So what im doing wrong for hook `wp_insert_site` ?

I really have no clue how to solve my issue at this point. I spend some time to find solution but I was not able to, and it is important to work correctly. Because I have more stuff to update for new created blog so user don't have to do (actually he will be not able to do) :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wpmu_new_blog` hook is indeed deprecated and shouldn't be used; however, it works because it runs after the new site has been initialized (see [`wp_initialize_site()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_initialize_site/)) which means the database tables for that site has been created and filled with the default options.

So because you are updating the site's options like `default_comment_status`, then you should use the [`wp_initialize_site` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_initialize_site/) and not `wp_insert_site`:

```php
add_action( 'wp_initialize_site', 'setup_multisite_action' ); // use this
//add_action( 'wp_insert_site', 'setup_multisite_action' );   // not this
```

Comment: Actually when I dump `$data` it is what I get: `object(WP_Site)#2091 (12) {
  ["blog_id"]=>
  string(2) "28"
  ["domain"]=>
  string(10) "advokat.wp"
  ["path"]=>
  string(12) "/xxccxxc345/"
  ["site_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["registered"]=>
  string(19) "2020-10-12 15:24:54"
  ["last_updated"]=>
  string(19) "2020-10-12 15:24:54"
  ["public"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["archived"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["mature"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["spam"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["deleted"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["lang_id"]=>
  string(1) "0"
}`

Comment: I see. But how about just trying it, or try with the `wp_initialize_site` hook instead?

Comment: `wp_initialize_site` Actaully this hook fixed my issue! Lol how I miss that! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about the initial answer... I should've looked a bit more at the function source :p